# Collaborative lock for "Daylight saving time and time zone best practices"?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, historical-lock

I came across this post:

- [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)

It was asked back in 2010, but is now clearly too broad. Its [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2532729/timeline) has two attempts at closure but those were invalidated.

The top answer clearly has a bunch of useful recommendations that will remain so for years to come.

I believe it deserves a collaborative lock.

Comment: Why is necessary to lock it? Where is it said that questions "deserve locking"?

Comment: @Braiam Old, now off topic (but still useful) questions usually get a historical lock.

Comment: @Magisch generally only when the post comes under a lot of contradictory activity (closed/re-opened/deleted/un-deleted etc...) Otherwise it's not really necessary.

Comment: @JonClements Well now it's certainly bound to attract some contradictory activity (and it already has, an attempt at closure in december 2016). Whats the harm in putting a historic lock on it now?

Comment: @Magisch because a lock is a last resort. It's causing no harm - it got left open in December... unless the community decides to go nuts with it there's no need to lock it. (It's also organically getting votes here and there - so a lock would also block the voting)

Comment: @Magisch and only when it's contradictory: if it's unanimous that is should be closed/deleted, there's no need to lock.